# Distribute data of one time series onto another

Tags: python, pandas

This is a contrived example to keep the data generation easy, but in general this should be a problem applicable to a wide audience.

I have a time-series of measurements like so:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: index = pd.date_range(start="18:10",periods=20,freq='min')

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(randn(20,3),columns=list('abc'),index=index)

In [4]: df.head()
Out[4]: 
                            a         b         c
2013-02-27 18:10:00 -1.344753  0.438351  1.561849
2013-02-27 18:11:00  1.715643  1.601984 -0.027408
2013-02-27 18:12:00 -0.142264 -0.049462  0.482493
2013-02-27 18:13:00  0.132617  0.737902 -0.347620
2013-02-27 18:14:00  1.277257  0.083401  0.649422
```

In between the 'real' measurements, calibration measurements are being done, but at a much lesser frequency than the measurements, e.g. something like this:

```
In [5]: calindex = pd.date_range("18:12:30",periods=4,freq='5min')

In [6]: caldata = pd.Series([10,20,30,40],index = calindex)

In [7]: caldata
Out[7]: 
2013-02-27 18:12:30    10
2013-02-27 18:17:30    20
2013-02-27 18:22:30    30
2013-02-27 18:27:30    40
Freq: 5T
```

The general idea now is to apply these calibration data to the measurements.
For this, I would like to distribute / broadcast the calibration data by a 'closest-time' approach, so I would like to generate another column called 'offsets' for example, that has *that* calibration value in each row of the measurements that was determined closest in time to the time of each measurement value.

Therefore I am after an end result like this:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
                            a         b         c  offsets
2013-02-27 18:10:00 -1.344753  0.438351  1.561849       10
2013-02-27 18:11:00  1.715643  1.601984 -0.027408       10
2013-02-27 18:12:00 -0.142264 -0.049462  0.482493       10
2013-02-27 18:13:00  0.132617  0.737902 -0.347620       10
2013-02-27 18:14:00  1.277257  0.083401  0.649422       10
2013-02-27 18:15:00  0.048120  0.421220  0.149372       20
2013-02-27 18:16:00  0.812317 -1.517389  2.035487       20
2013-02-27 18:17:00 -0.058959 -0.034876 -1.535118       20
2013-02-27 18:18:00 -0.666227  0.040208 -1.042464       20
2013-02-27 18:19:00 -0.077031 -0.158351 -0.441992       20
2013-02-27 18:20:00  0.103083 -0.129341  0.294073       30
2013-02-27 18:21:00  0.900802  0.443271 -0.946229       30
2013-02-27 18:22:00  0.744631 -0.058666 -0.386226       30
2013-02-27 18:23:00 -0.064313  0.500321 -0.536237       30
2013-02-27 18:24:00 -0.392653  0.789827  0.000109       30
2013-02-27 18:25:00  1.926765  0.252259 -0.051475       40
2013-02-27 18:26:00 -0.035577  0.559222 -0.290751       40
2013-02-27 18:27:00  1.726165  0.626515 -0.868177       40
2013-02-27 18:28:00  1.269409  1.520980 -0.181637       40
2013-02-27 18:29:00 -1.151166 -0.300196  0.420747       40
```

The application of values into other columns via .map, .apply, etc. I believe to understand well, it is the apparently required time or offset trickery one needs to do for the distribution of the values that I don't have a clue what to start with.

Should it maybe be attacked with pandas.DateOffsets? Is there machinery to minimize time-deltas inside pandas somewhere?

I would appreciate a nudge into the right direction, doesn't have to be complete at all, just the direction where I need to be going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use numpy functions to calculate the nearest time location:

```
from numpy.random import randn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range(start="18:10",periods=20,freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(20,3),columns=list('abc'),index=index)
calindex = pd.date_range("18:12:30",periods=4,freq='5min')
caldata = pd.Series([10,20,30,40],index = calindex)

# if you use numpy 1.7
real_time = df.index.values
cali_time = caldata.index.values

# if you use numpy 1.6
real_time = np.array(df.index.values.view("i8") / 1000, dtype="datetime64[us]")
cali_time = np.array(caldata.index.values.view("i8") / 1000, dtype="datetime64[us]")

right_index = cali_time.searchsorted(real_time, side="left")
left_index = np.clip(right_index - 1, 0, len(caldata)-1)
right_index = np.clip(right_index, 0, len(caldata)-1)
left_time = cali_time[left_index]
right_time = cali_time[right_index]
left_diff = np.abs(left_time - real_time)
right_diff = np.abs(right_time - real_time)
caldata2 = caldata[np.where(left_diff < right_diff, left_time, right_time)]
df["offset"] = caldata2.values
```

Comment: Thanks! But: 'l' and 'r' are undefined?

Comment: i tried to use it but receive errors: left_diff and right_diff are not displayable in an ipython console, i get the error "TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to int). And the np.where breaks with the error "TypeError: ufunc 'less' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coercedto any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'"

Comment: actually, cali_time is an np.array, while df.index is a pandas.DatetimeIndex, can this be the problem?

Comment: I tried the left_diff/right_diff calculation with using df.index.values instead, but because of numpy's inability to treat the timedelta64 type correctly, things are totally messed up. The np.where() gives 45129 as year!

Comment: Maybe there are some version problem, I changed the code, please try again. I am using NumPy 1.7, Pandas 0.10. This time, the dtype of left_diff will be timedelta64[ns].

Comment: I'm using np 1.6.1 and pd 0.10.1, and the np.where result still is messed up: np.where(left_diff < right_diff, left_time, right_time):
array([45129-09-15 16:20:00, 45129-09-15 16:20:00, 45129-09-15 16:20:00, 45129-09-15 16:20:00, 45129-09-15 16:20:00, 45129-09-19 03:40:00, 45129-09-19 03:40:00, 45129-09-19 03:40:00, 45129-09-19 03:40:00, 45129-09-19 03:40:00, 45129-09-22 15:00:00, 45129-09-22 15:00:00, 45129-09-22 15:00:00, 45129-09-22 15:00:00, 45129-09-22 15:00:00, [...], 45129-09-26 02:20:00], dtype=datetime64[us])

Comment: I tested my code in numpy 1.6, the same problem. So maybe there are some bugs with datetime array in numpy 1.6.

Comment: Finally, I found the bug, numpy 1.6 can't deal with datetime64[ns], so I changed the code that convert ns array to us array. It worked on my PC with numpy 1.6.

Comment: A (late) comment: a slightly slicker way to find the insertion points is to compute the halfway boundaries in `cali_time` first (e.g., `halfway = cali_time[:-1] + 0.5 * (cali_time[1:] - cali_time[:-1])`), and then call `searchsorted` on `halfway` instead of on `cali_time`.  That saves you from having to do the later comparison to determine which of the two nearby `cali` values is closest.  This approach is working for me with NumPy 1.7;  I haven't tried it with NumPy 1.6.